# How to generalize this C# code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code which initializes winforms textboxes.

```
txt0.Text = steps[0];
txt1.Text = steps[1];
txt2.Text = steps[2];
txt3.Text = steps[3];
```

I'd like to generalize it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++)
{
    txti.Text = steps[i];
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because `the name txti does not exist in current context`. 
How to make it work?

EDIT:
I want to avoid creating all the textboxes and picture boxes in code and adding them to tablelayoutpanel in code.

Comment: You should have an array or list of textboxes, not four different ones. So instead of `txt0`... you should have `txt[i]`.

Comment: Is this winforms? wpf? webforms? asp.net mvc? silverlight? some other ui framework I forgot about?

Comment: it's winforms and I don't know how to create array of all textboxes there

Comment: `Form` has some methods to enumerate controls it contains, so maybe you could construct your array by searching the form (or a subset of it) for the textbox instances you care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the original question could be generalized as follows.

```
var TextBoxes = new TextBox[]{ txt0, txt1, txt2, txt3 };
for (int i = 0; i < TextBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    TextBoxes[i].Text = steps[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You were the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with reflection, but i wouldn't recommend it to solve this task.

Instead have a List and loop through it.

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox> {txt0,txt1,txt2,txt3};
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{ 
    textBoxes[i].Text = steps[i];
}
```

Comment: Why you even mentioned reflection here then? :)

Comment: What about styling the textboxes and adding them to container using code when I already created it in designer? Sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: @Fabio, true - i should remove it.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Why nightmare, there's nothing that changes for you. you keep everything as is. Just have a list of your textboxes

Comment: Aha sorry I just glanced over first line of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the type cast to reference the textboxes dynamically.

```
for (int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++)
{
    TextBox txt = this.FindControl("txt" + i.ToString()) as TextBox;
    txt.Text = steps[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: When using `FindControl`, it would be necessary checking for `null`

Comment: Would this return the list in the right order though?

Comment: @user5226582: FindControl is finding the individual control by name - "txt" + i.ToString() - so should only return a single value. It may be a good idea to check for null return value in case of wrong naming though

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding controls by their names:

```
for (int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++)
  Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].Text = steps[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's `WinForms` you can use `Name` property of your `TextBox`.

```
for( int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++ )
{
    TextBox tBox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "txt" + i);
    if(tBox == null) break;

    tBox.Text = steps[i];
}
```

`Name` property of your `Control` corresponds with the variable name you use meaning that if you call your `TextBox` as `txt0` it's name is `"txt0"` which makes it really easy to retrieve from it's parent `Control` using this name.

Answer (score 1):

Winforms has "right" controls for displaying collection data - `DataGridView` for example.

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = steps.ToList();
```

`DataGridView` will generate rows and one column which will contain values of `steps`. For automated generating column you need to be sure that `yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true` - (it is `true` by default)

You can "style" generated cells by using `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle` property or others.

If you need display images besides text then `DataGridView` seems "right" choice.
Create a class which represents your data structure of step

```
public class Step
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Image StatusImage { get; set; }
}

// Create collection
var steps = new List<Step>
{
    new Step { Name = "One", StatusImage = image1 },
    new Step { Name = "Two", StatusImage = image1 },
    new Step { Name = "Three", StatusImage = image1 }
}

yourDataGridView.DataSource = steps;
```

`DataGridView` should generate `DataGridViewImageColumn` for `StatusImage` property.

If you have an enum for `StepStatus` instead of image. Then you can use `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event to convert enum to the image.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't in the question, but every textbox has associated picturebox with status image after step is done. Not sure how I'd use that and I never used winforms DataGridView.

Comment: You can show image in `DataGridVIewImageColumn`, check updated answer.